# Custom boards list

Tags: arduino-ide, ide

Is there a simple way to create or modify my boards list? I find having a full library listing confusing. I have about 6 boards I program regularly, but using the listings from the board manager gives me about 60 things to look through, which gets tedious fast.

Here is a list of MCUs I frequently use:

- Teensy2.0
- Adafruit Trinket 16Mhz
- Adafruit Trinket Pro 16MHz
- Adafruit Circuit Playground
- Adafruit feather Huzzah
- Arduino Uno R3

How can I make a boards list that only includes the boards I own?

Answer (score 1):

Throwing out the unneeded boards from the boards.txt files will do what you want.

Comment: where is that? in the arduino directory?  Im on linux, I will look for it.

Comment: Avr boards are in arduino install/hardware. Boardmanager installs are at  ~/.arduino15/packages on linux.